# How to curl the results of a form submission

Tags: php, forms, redirect, curl

I'm trying to make a page that submits a form to a page on another website, then retrieves the "results page" html and stores it as a variable.

The problem is two fold: First, I'm too much of a programming novice to know what to search for even though I've Googled for days (I originally tried doing this in frames and learned about SOP).  Second, if I simply submit the form it correctly loads on the next page on the other domain, but that page does some things and then redirects to a page that has the actual results I want.

Everything about the form submission itself works fine, I just have no idea how to pull the results (the HTML of the ultimate page it redirects to) as a variable in PHP.

It goes:

```
mysite.com/mypage.php
```

to

```
othersite.com/results1.php?session_key=abcdefghi123
```

to

```
othersite.com/results2.php?session_key=abcdefghi123
```

I need the html from the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this, where the array of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS are your html form fields.

```
$h = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, "path/to/form.php"); 
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'txtfield1' => 'x',
  'txtfield2' => 'y'
  ));
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $result = curl_exec($h);
  echo $result;
```

Reading the question again, in regards to the redirect. 
See "Du D's" comment below, you will need that line also

Comment: I think his page redirect to another page, so you might have to add this option to allow curl to follow the redirect.  

curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);